# Bootstrap-switch doesn´t event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have the following html code (working properly changing the state of the checkbox) and I need to run an alert when the state of some checkbox is changed.

```
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE1" class="alert-status">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE2" class="alert-status">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE3" class="alert-status">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE4" class="alert-status">
</div>
```

I have tried the following combinations, but I can not execute the routine:

1)

```
$('.make-switch.input[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
          console.log(this); // DOM element
          console.log(event); // jQuery event
          console.log(state); // true | false
          alert(this);
});
```

2)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
          console.log(this); // DOM element
          console.log(event); // jQuery event
          console.log(state); // true | false
          alert(this);
});
```

3)

```
$('.alert-status').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
          console.log(this); // DOM element
          console.log(event); // jQuery event
          console.log(state); // true | false
          alert(this);
});
```

4)

```
$('.alert-status').on('switchChange', function(event, state) {
          console.log(this); // DOM element
          console.log(event); // jQuery event
          console.log(state); // true | false
          alert(this);
});
```

5)

```
/*$(".alert-status").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          alert($(this).attr('data-checkbox'));
});*/
```

I have searched the internet, I have consulted examples, I have used with firebug, and I find no way to capture the event. Can anyone help me?

I found this example and have modified and work in this environment, not on my website:

http://jsfiddle.net/sumw4/13/ (I add probeProbe class and portion of code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your code should be working http://jsfiddle.net/PNU45/

```
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE1" class="alert-status">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE2" class="alert-status">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE3" class="alert-status">
</div>
<div class="make-switch switch-small">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE4" class="alert-status">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.alert-status').bootstrapSwitch('state', true);


$('.alert-status').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {

    alert($(this).data('checkbox'));
    //alert(event);
   // alert(state);
});
```

Comment: I have pasted this code into my web and does not work. I enabled firebug to detect a possible error and can not find any errors, except the following: Error: Method does not exit state! localhost/j/jquery-1.9.1.js line 6 It is very rare and I do not get it working. The checkbox changes from ON to OFF, but does not trigger the event. Thank you very much. regards

Comment: It is very curious, I finally changed my files "bootstrap-switch.min.js" and "bootstrap-switch.css" by the direction of his examples and has worked for me ... Thanks @Mr.Cocococo !

Answer (score 3):

try this :

get state

```
$('.alert-status').bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
```

On change

```
$('.alert-status').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
 if (state) {
    // true
 } else {
    // false
 }
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem with bootstrapSwitch 3. So, after trying a lot of variants unsuccessfully, I decided to test the code directly. And after all, this is my solution (at least under Chrome, have to test under the other bundle of browsers)

having this HTML...

```
<div class="make-switch switch-small"> 
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" data-checkbox="VALUE1" class="alert-status">
</div>
```

this javascript works perfectly for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
       function value1Changed(event, state){
          var myNewState = state.value;
       }

       $('input[data-checkbox="VALUE1"]')
          .parent('.make-switch')
          .on('switch-change', value1Changed);
   });
</script>
```

Hope it can help!!